# imagecreatefrombmp not working on php

Tags: php, image, bmp

i am trying to half the size of bmp image from php. PHO gd doesnt have a imagecreatefrombmp so i have to include seperate function. But my code doesnt seems to be working. It works well with jpeg. Here is my code it should display half the image of bmp image test.bmp

```
<?php


if (!function_exists("imagecreatefrombmp")) {
    function imagecreatefrombmp( $filename ) {
        $file = fopen( $filename, "rb" );
        $read = fread( $file, 10 );
        while( !feof( $file ) && $read != "" )
        {
            $read .= fread( $file, 1024 );
        }
        $temp = unpack( "H*", $read );
        $hex = $temp[1];
        $header = substr( $hex, 0, 104 );
        $body = str_split( substr( $hex, 108 ), 6 );
        if( substr( $header, 0, 4 ) == "424d" )
        {
            $header = substr( $header, 4 );
            // Remove some stuff?
            $header = substr( $header, 32 );
            // Get the width
            $width = hexdec( substr( $header, 0, 2 ) );
            // Remove some stuff?
            $header = substr( $header, 8 );
            // Get the height
            $height = hexdec( substr( $header, 0, 2 ) );
            unset( $header );
        }
        $x = 0;
        $y = 1;
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
        foreach( $body as $rgb )
        {
            $r = hexdec( substr( $rgb, 4, 2 ) );
            $g = hexdec( substr( $rgb, 2, 2 ) );
            $b = hexdec( substr( $rgb, 0, 2 ) );
            $color = imagecolorallocate( $image, $r, $g, $b );
            imagesetpixel( $image, $x, $height-$y, $color );
            $x++;
            if( $x >= $width )
            {
                $x = 0;
                $y++;
            }
        }
        return $image;
    }
}
// File and new size
$filename = 'wheat.bmp';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/bmp');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefrombmp($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Comment: so how actually it doesn't seem to be working? what works and what doesn't?

Comment: it just a bank page the half size picture does not get displayed

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was also throwing the same error as below.

> Call to undefined function imagecreatefrombmp()

Even When I was on php version PHP Version 7.1.28

So, I defined this function as

```
function imagecreatefrombmp($p_sFile)
{
    $file    =    fopen($p_sFile,"rb");
    $read    =    fread($file,10);
    while(!feof($file)&&($read<>""))
    $read    .=    fread($file,1024);
    $temp    =    unpack("H*",$read);
    $hex    =    $temp[1];
    $header    =    substr($hex,0,108);
    if (substr($header,0,4)=="424d")
    {
        $header_parts    =    str_split($header,2);
        $width            =    hexdec($header_parts[19].$header_parts[18]);
        $height            =    hexdec($header_parts[23].$header_parts[22]);
        unset($header_parts);
    }
    $x                =    0;
    $y                =    1;
    $image            =    imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    $body            =    substr($hex,108);
    $body_size        =    (strlen($body)/2);
    $header_size    =    ($width*$height);
    $usePadding        =    ($body_size>($header_size*3)+4);
    for ($i=0;$i<$body_size;$i+=3)
    {
        if ($x>=$width)
        {
            if ($usePadding)
                $i    +=    $width%4;
            $x    =    0;
            $y++;
            if ($y>$height)
                break;
        }
        $i_pos    =    $i*2;
        $r        =    hexdec($body[$i_pos+4].$body[$i_pos+5]);
        $g        =    hexdec($body[$i_pos+2].$body[$i_pos+3]);
        $b        =    hexdec($body[$i_pos].$body[$i_pos+1]);
        $color    =    imagecolorallocate($image,$r,$g,$b);
        imagesetpixel($image,$x,$height-$y,$color);
        $x++;
    }
    unset($body);
    return $image;
}
```

As an argument, I passed relative path of the file. i.e. `(upload/images/example.bmp)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `imagecreatefromwbmp()`. This is the right function to convert images as bmp file.

Comment: The documentation indicated this is a wireless bitmap specification that is different from the windows bitmap image format.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently imagecreatefrombmp() is now included in PHP 7.